# Can these simultaneously be integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to figure out if there exist $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$ ($\omega>0$ and  $\omega$ is **not** odd) such that
\begin{align}
\frac{k}{1+\omega} +\frac12  \quad \text{and}  \quad  \frac{k}{1+\tfrac{1}{\omega}} +\frac12 \\
\end{align}
are both integers  strictly greater than $1$.

I know I have a possibly strange constraint on $\omega$ but it is relevant to the problem I am trying to work on.

Assuming that $\frac{k}{1+\omega} +\frac12  = n $ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and
$ \frac{k}{1+\tfrac{1}{\omega}} +\frac12 =m $ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$

I arrive at
\begin{equation}
(2n-1)(1+\omega) = (2m-1)(1+\tfrac{1}{\omega})
\end{equation}

My suspicion is that there is no solution to this problem, and I tried to arrive at a contradiction that $\omega$ would have to be odd.

Is this the right approach? Or is my conjecture false and there is a solution?

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: @projectilemotion thank you, but I intend for $\omega$ to possibly be a real number. I was debating whether to write it as $\mathbb{R}_{>0} \backslash \{ 2n-1\} $ because saying it is not odd could be confusing and suggest it is even.

Comment: @projectilemotion Unless I'm missing something, it is the two expressions on the first line I have written that I want strictly larger than one.

Comment: @projectilemotion Thanks for the edits!

Comment: No problem, I hope this makes it clearer. In that case, @RobertIsrael's answer answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{k}{1+\omega}+\frac{1}{2} = m $$
is equivalent to $$ \omega = \frac{2k}{2m-1} - 1 $$
Here $\omega$ will not be an odd integer if $k$ is not a multiple of $2m-1$.
Now
$$ \frac{k}{1+1/\omega} + \frac{1}{2} = k - m + 1 $$
so if $m$ and $k$ are integers, this is automatically an integer.  You also want $m > 1$ and $k - m + 1 > 1$, and this is easy to arrange.  For example, take $m = 3$, $k = 4$, $\omega = 3/5$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
(2n-1)(1+\omega) = (2m-1)(1+\tfrac{1}{\omega}) \Leftrightarrow \\
\omega(2n-1)=(2m-1) \Leftrightarrow \\
\omega =\frac{2m-1}{2n-1}
$$
set
$$
k=m+n-1
$$

Then
$$
\frac{k}{1+\omega} +\frac12 = \frac{m+n-1}{\frac{2m+2n-2}{2n-1}}+\frac{1}{2}=m \\
\frac{k}{1+\tfrac{1}{\omega}} +\frac12 =\frac{m+n-1}{\frac{2m+2n-2}{2m-1}}+\frac{1}{2}=n\\
$$

Answer (score 0):

$2m-1$ is odd while $\frac{\omega+1}{\omega}$ has an even denominator and odd numerator, so product ($\frac{odd}{even})$ of these terms cannot be integer .

Comment: Are you assuming $\omega$ is an integer?

Comment: @Robert Israel I assume that $\omega$ is an even integer - implied from his restriction that it is not odd.  If it can be a fraction With both numerator and denominator odd, then solution is possible.